# Static initialization of local variables

Tags: c++, initialization

From Scott Meyers **Effective C++**:

> if you never call a function emulating a non-local static object, you
>   never incur the cost of constructing and destructing the object,
>   something that can’t be said for true non-local static objects.

The function:

```
FileSystem& tfs()
{ 
    static FileSystem fs;
    return fs; 
}
```

But the Standard said:

> Constant initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static
>   storage duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is
>   first entered. **An implementation is permitted to perform early**
>   **initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread**
>   **storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is**
>   **permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread**
>   **storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2).**

That means that we can't say for sure if the `fs` variable is or is not initialized even if we don't call to the function `tfs()`. Because implementation is permitted to perform early initialization as for variables with static storage duration.

Who was right or what did I miss?

Comment: When in doubt, trust the spec. Effective C++ was published in 1992, perhaps things has changed.

Answer (score 7):

[Constant initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) describes initialization that can be determined at compile-time.

Only in C++11 and later can a type with a non-trivial constructor be considered:

> if the constructor is `constexpr`

In "Effective C++", Meyers describes the class in your question literally as:

> `class FileSystem {...};`

This would imply that given the C++ Standard being correct, "Effective C++" can also remain correct *even after* C++11 as long as the supplied constructor for `FileSystem` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: Is it really correct to talk about initialization at compile-time? I mean, constant initialization's performed when program is being started (or deffered to some statement of `main()`).

Comment: And one more thing, the constexpr ontructor will guerantee that the inialization is a const initialization. So it will be performed when the block first entered?

Comment: @Stella - A constexpr constructor *allows* the value to be known at compile time, but it also requires all parameters to be constant expressions as well. Anyway, there is no runtime cost for initialization if the  compiler can include an already constructed object in the executable file.